# Outlook 2010 avoid printing my name at top of email

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, printing

I want to print out an email someone else sent.

I want to keep it exactly the same, but when I print it, it puts my name at the top of the sheet. I don't want my name to appear. Solution?

Comment: http://www.slipstick.com/problems/how-do-i-remove-my-name-when-i-print-email/

Comment: Just use `Print selection`